# Generating a P&L that is linear in the variation on an underlying at no cost

Tags: pricing, pnl

I am actually reading Lorenzo Bergomi's "Stochastic Volatility Modelling" book, and came across this bit :

[image]

I understand everything up to (5.5) included. But I don't see the point in mentioning the vanishing pricing drift. What is "pricing drift" ? After that he defines continuous (instantaneous in fact) VS forward variance and writes that they are driftless as well (same argument as for discrete VS forward variance), and write that in a diffusive setting they are equal to $\left(\ldots\right) dW_t^T$ where I guess $W^T$ is a standard Brownian motion under the forward $T$ measure.

Is pricing drift defined outside a diffusive setting or does everything here takes place in a diffusive setting ? (The "in a diffusive setting" is unsettling.)

What is general in Bergomi's remark about pricing drift ? I mean, is there a way to define being a martingle through linearity of a certain P&L or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

He's basically making a parallel between a forward variance trade and a futures trade. In both cases you should have that the underlying quotes are martingales in the absence of arbitrage.

**Long(er) answer**

Under the physical measure $\Bbb{P}$, an arbitrage is a (self-financing) trading strategy $V$ - or rather the value of a portfolio implementing this strategy - for which there exists a time $T > 0$ such that
$$ V_0=0,\,\, V_T \geq 0\,\, \Bbb{P}-\text{a.s. and } \Bbb{P}(V_T \ne 0) > 0$$

Suppose you define an **equivalent** probability measure $\Bbb{Q}\equiv\Bbb{P}$. Since by definition, both measures agree on null events, our arbitrage definition translates to
$$ V_0=0,\,\, V_T \geq 0\,\, \Bbb{Q}-\text{a.s. and } \Bbb{Q}(V_T \ne 0) > 0 \tag{A}$$

Notice that if $\Bbb{Q}$ is further a **martingale** measure, that is if $(V_t)_{t\geq0}$ emerges as a $\Bbb{Q}$-martingale:
$$ V_0 = \Bbb{E}_0^\Bbb{Q} [ V_T ] $$
then $(A)$ will never happen. This explains the central role of *equivalent martingale measures* in arbitrage pricing theory.

Putting that back into context, you've managed to identify a (self-financing) strategy (i.e. buying and selling forward variance swaps), which at no cost ($V_t=0$), allows you to earn a quantity $$V_{t'} = (T_2-T_1) \left( \hat{\sigma}_{VS,T_1T_2}^2(t') - \hat{\sigma}_{VS,T_1T_2}^2(t)\right)$$

Based on what we've said earlier, in the absence of arbitrage, there should exist a measure $\Bbb{Q} \equiv \Bbb{P}$ such that
$$ \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}_{t}[V_{t'}] = V_t$$
hence, using the definitions of $V_t$ and $V_{t'}$,
$$ \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}_{t}\left[ \hat{\sigma}_{VS,T_1T_2}^2(t') \right] = \hat{\sigma}_{VS,T_1T_2}^2(t) $$
hence forward variance swap quotes are martingales. Assuming a *continuous paths* process (= in a *diffusive setting*), by the **martingale representation theorem** we should then have
$$ \hat{\sigma}_{VS,T_1T_2}^2(t) = ... dW_t^\Bbb{Q} $$
hence no pricing drift under $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: This makes total sense to me. Two questions though : 1) "a parallel between a forward variance trade and a futures trade" : you would use the same approach to show that a futures rate is martingale under the spot measure then ? I never understood the argument in the futures context because of margining. Could we show a futures is a "spot martingale" be saying it a rolled position of one-day forwards ? 2) How far does non arbitrage theory go without resorting to diffusions ?

Comment: Assume that, over a given trading day, you enter a future position at $t$ and unwind it before the close at $t'$. At the end of the day, the clearing house credits/debits your margin account of the quantity $F(t',T)-F(t,T)$. Can you see the parallel now?

Comment: You get that $\Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}_{t}\left[ F(t',T) - F(t,T)\right] = 0$ as we entered at no cost, which gives the martingale relation as $F(t,T)$ is $\mathscr{F}_t$_measurable ? So basically  the "linearity of the P&L in variation of the underlying" is just what allows you to do this cond. exp. calculation ? Why cannot I do the same for a forward ? I always tended to see that the fwd $T$ measure degenerates to the spot measure as $T-t\rightarrow 0$, but I may be wrong ?

Comment: About futures, should I forget the following description seen in Bjork's Arbitrage Theory in continuous time : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMYb5.jpg ?

Comment: Yes. No. Yes, the same can be done for the forward. No the 2 measures coincide for deterministic rates. This is exactly the futures definition I used. Don't confuse the value of a future contract and the future price (same goes for forward). See here http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31162/is-forward-price-trendless-under-the-real-world-measure.

Comment: There's still somthing I don't : how is determined through our non-arbitrage argument the measure under which our "driftless" underlying will be a martingale ? Because, if I am not wrong, instead of writing $\Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}_{t}\left[ F(t',T) - F(t,T)\right] = 0$ I could have written $\Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q^{\ast}}_{t}\left[ F(t',T) - F(t,T)\right] = 0$ for any other measure $\Bbb{Q}^{\ast}$ and $F(t,T)$ would still be a $\Bbb{Q}^{\ast}$-martingale, because the fact that $F(t,T)$ is $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable is measure independant. Am I wrong ?

Comment: (I am coming up with this becaus I tried to do the same argument with a forward or more generally with a swap, without success, where I know that the right measure is not the bank account measure.)

Comment: e.g. forward price $F(0,T)$ is defined as the strike $K$ such that $ \Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}[(B_T)^{-1}(S_T - K)] = 0$. From there you have $F(0,T) = \frac{\Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}[ B_T^{-1} S_T ]}{\Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}[ B_T^{-1} ]}$, defining $\Bbb{Q}^T \equiv \Bbb{Q}$ through $\left. \frac{d\Bbb{Q}^T}{d\Bbb{Q}} \right\vert_{\mathcal{F}_T} = \frac{B_T^{-1}}{\Bbb{E}^\Bbb{Q}[ B_T^{-1} ]} = \frac{1}{B_T P(0,T)}$, thus allows you to write: $F(0,T) = \Bbb{E}^{\Bbb{Q}^T}[S_T]$, and since $S_T=F(T,T)$ you have that forward price is a $\Bbb{Q}^T$ martingale.

Comment: Actually, you should ask this in a separate question if you don't mind as it pollutes the Q&A format. Also I only provided a glimpse at the pricing theory. Notably my argument is if there exists such $\Bbb{Q}$ then there cannot be arbitrage, but I do not demonstrate do it the other way around. And in practice indeed it is the value of self-financing strategies that, when expressed wrt to a given numéraire, should emerge as martingales in the EMM induced by that numéraire. I only wanted to give you an idea of what happens, not a rigorous theoretical background.

Comment: Just one point : I know all that stuff from a measure change pov, my main question is : how would have Bergomi done in its framework (he's rarely precising measures he uses, only writing "linear P&Ls"...) But thx a lot anyway for your thorough answer !

Comment: He's simply assuming a money market account numéraire to account for the time value of money IMHO. In other words, he applies his reasonings to *discounted* P&L